# How to get discord bot to create a channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a script that **scrapes** info from a webpage. I want my discord bot to create a channel with the product title from the webpage (This product title will be different every time depending on which page I am scraping). Anyway, I would like it to **scrape** the webpage, read the title of the product, create a channel with said product name and then send the embed in that new channel it created. If you need any more info please just ask I will try to answer best as I can, I am fairly new to coding...

```
async def start(ctx):

Code that __scrapes__ webpage...

# Discord Embed Setup   
    embed = Embed(
        description=" ",
        color=0x0d0d22,
        timestamp='now'  # sets the timestamp to current time
        )#f'[{name}]({link})'

    embed.set_title(title="**__"+Titles+"__**", url=ProductLink)

    embed.add_field(name="**Release Date**", value=Dates, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**Retail**", value=Prices, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**Colorway**", value=ColorWay, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**PID**", value=PIDs, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**Raffle**", value="**"+f'[{Link}]({RaffleLink})'+"**", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="**Resell**", value="**"+f'[{stock}]({StockXSearch})'+"|"+f'[{goat}]({GoatSearch})'+"**", inline=False)

    embed.set_footer(text='Test', icon_url=ICON)

    embed.set_image(image.get_attribute('src'))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    print("Embed sent to discord!")

@client.command()
async def release(ctx):
    await start(ctx)
```

Comment: You want the `create_text_channel` method of a Guild (server) object.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea how to do that. I have tried multiple ways but always run into errors. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Well, `client.guilds` will return the guilds (servers) hosting the bot. Find the correct one (the first and only one?), which I'll call `guild`. Then use `await guild.create_text_channel("Channel Name")`. Show your effort and the errors you are getting. You're question currently includes code weirdly unrelated to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it like this and send a message to it.

```
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx):
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('Name here')
    await channel.send('Text in channel')
```

Comment: This creates the channel but does not send the message I get the error ```Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'channel' is not defined```

Comment: I did it on my part and it worked [image](https://imgur.com/Bd8uiTw) Make sure that the bot has permission to see the channel.

Comment: The bot has admin perms.

Comment: What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like the guy above me but if you want to do your own name for the channel you can do:

```
@bot.command()
async def create(ctx, name):
    channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(name)
    await channel.send('Text in channel')
```